# SSRS - Export to Excel Should Execute a Second Dataset Only

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, export-to-excel, ssrs-2016

I have two queries, one: fast query with few columns; second: with more columns (which is slow).

Now, I want the report to execute only the fast dataset/query with few columns so that the report will display output efficiently. Second slow query/dataset should not be executed at this level.

On clicking the Export to Excel button should execute the second slow query/dataset with all the columns and export only this output with all columns. But report with few columns should not be included in the exported excel output file.

Can someone please help ? ?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Comment: Do you have a custom button that renders the report in excel using an Action or are you expecting the - Export as -> Excel to do this?

Comment: Hi Harry, no I am using the builtin Export to Excel functionality.

May I ask, how could it be done with custom button ? ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use the `Globals!RenderFormat`.

You can toggle the hidden property of the UI element related to the long running export based on the render format.

```
<YourExportData.Hidden>=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL", false, true)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ross.

May I ask please, if this prevents the execution of the slow Dataset until the "Export to Excel" button is clicked ? ?

Comment: If the element bound to the dataset is hidden then  the dataset will  not execute the command.

Comment: Thanks Ross. This is what I want if it does not execute the long running report. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ross,
this does not seem to have worked.

I am using SQL Server 2016.

It hides the second Tablix in the report display and includes it in the Export to Excel, when I use the statement in the Tablix property Visibility "=IIf(not(Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive), false,true)"

But it does not hide the Tablix in the report output display page and shows it on the next page when I use the statement "=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL", true, false)"

Any idea please ? ? ?

Regards,